# The relationship between Bellman Equation and EM(Expectation Maximisation) Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, probability, reinforcement-learning

Today I came across **Value Evaluation Algorithm** under the topic of **Bellman Equation** when learning reinforcement learning, which is stated as:

- While not converged:

  - **Policy Update**: $\pi_{k+1} =\arg\max_{\pi}(\gamma_{\pi} + \gamma P_{\pi}v_k)$
  - **Value Update**: $v_{k+1} = r_{\pi_{k+1}} + \gamma P_{\pi_{k+1}}v_k$

This algorithm really reminds me of EM. Because we first initialize our $v$ randomly, then we find the best policy that will yield the maximum state value. After that, we calculate state value $v$ again based on the policy we have determined earlier.

Does it mean that Value Evaluation is a special case of EM algorithm? What's the intuition or math behind it?